# Hibernate saveOrUpdate session not working

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and was working on a project where I want to update the expiry date of membership when someone buys the membership. i have written a class implementing the AtributeConverter.
Upon calling the buyMembership method, both print methods are printing the correct date but database is not getting updated. In console, it shows that only select query is running. The update query is being executed. Refer code for referrence

**USER_LOGIN Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login")
public class User_Login {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled = false;
    
    @Column(name="start_date")
    private LocalDate startDate;
    
    @Column(name="end_date")
    private LocalDate expiryDate;
```

**Repository**

```
public void buyMembership(String months,String email) {
        
        Session currentSession = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        User_Login user = currentSession.get(User_Login.class, email);
        
        LocalDate date = user.getExpiryDate();
        
        LocalDate current = LocalDate.now();
        
        if(date.compareTo(current)<0) {
            user.setStartDate(current);
            LocalDate newExpiryDate = current.plusMonths(Long.parseLong(months));
            System.out.println(newExpiryDate);
            user.setExpiryDate(newExpiryDate);
            user.setStartDate(current);
            //currentSession.saveOrUpdate(user);
        }
        else {
            LocalDate newExpiryDate = date.plusMonths(Long.parseLong(months));
            System.out.println(newExpiryDate);
            user.setExpiryDate(newExpiryDate);
            user.setStartDate(current);
            System.out.println(user.getExpiryDate());
            //currentSession.saveOrUpdate(user);
        }
        currentSession.update(user);
    
    }
```

*Attribute Converter**

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate attribute) {
        if(attribute==null)
            return null;
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date dbData) {

        if(dbData==null)
            return null;
        return dbData.toLocalDate();
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the session? Just use the `EntityManager` and use `find` instead of `get` and make sure your method (or service) is `@Transactional`. Finally you don't need the attribute converter as HIbernate can convert this itself (when using a modern version).

Comment: Ahh, Thanks @M.Denium, I just missed marking my service as transactional. Such minor mistakes... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a silly error. I had just missed marking my buyMembership service as transactional. After that,It worked like a charm...